# generating dynamic bootstrap accordion using coldfusion cfloop

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, coldfusion

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
                <cfloop query="qry_status" >
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title" >
                                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">1) What is HTML?</a>
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div id="#str_isp_status#" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <p>HTML stands for HyperText Markup Language. HTML is the main markup language for describing the structure of Web pages. <a href="http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/html-tutorial/" target="_blank">Learn more.</a></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </cfloop>
</div>
```

When I try to loop through the above code it does display the different rows but when I try to expand a row it does not work. The goal is to generate different rows dynamically and be able to expand/close each row independently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `href` attribute of anchor tag has a value `#collapseOne` but you are assigning the collapsible `DIV`'s a different ID using `str_isp_status`.

So, you can try this:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <cfoutput query="qry_status">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="##accordion" href="###str_isp_status#">1) What is HTML?</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="#str_isp_status#" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <p>HTML stands for HyperText Markup Language. HTML is the main markup language for describing the structure of Web pages. <a href="http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/html-tutorial/" target="_blank">Learn more.</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </cfoutput>
</div>
```

*Not related to question:* You will get an error when you will wrap the `cfloop` tag with a `cfoutput` tag because you have used a single **pound** (#) in `href` and `data-parent` attribute.